# Algorithm for best plan to killing enemies

Tags: algorithm

Viego is a powerful champion and there is a battle for him to kill all enemies.
Viego has a *magic* and he will use it to kill enemies as follows:

1. Viego selects an enemy and deals him `damage` damage.
2. if Viego kills an enemy, he partially recharges the magic and he can use it again at the next second, but the damage reduces by `damageReduction`, this mechanism can take effect multiple times, but the damage is at least 0.
   (alternatively, Viego could give up this chance and prepare for the next magic)
3. It takes 5 seconds for Viego to prepare the magic. Casting the magic takes no time.

Time is measured in seconds. Viego can cast his magic at the very beginning(the 0th second).

What is the best plan for Viego to spend the least time to kill all the enemies?
(for a bargain, the function could just return the least time.)

```
def bestKillingPlan(damage: int, damageReduction: int, enemies: List[int]) -> int:
    pass

test_case = [
{'damage':100, 'damageReduction': 22, 'enemies':[98], 'answer':0},
{'damage':100, 'damageReduction': 17, 'enemies':[236], 'answer':10},
{'damage': 10, 'damageReduction':  3, 'enemies':[10, 7, 4, 1], 'answer':3},
{'damage':300, 'damageReduction':100, 'enemies':[400,300,300], 'answer':7},
{'damage':500, 'damageReduction':100, 'enemies':[900,500,400,200,300], 'answer':9}
]
```

for the 4th test case, Viego's plan could be:

```
seconds|enemy_index
      0|          1
      1|          0
      6|          2
      7|          0
```

Comment: Please [state who originated this problem and where you found it](/help/referencing). Where is your own effort?

Comment: I came up this question when I playing LOL teamfight tactics, Viego in LOL has similar skill to what I said, maybe there is someone originated before me but I don't know how to find if he/she exists. I'm sorry I have no ideas at all about this problem, so I didn't write my own effort

Comment: Two algorithm paradigms are *greedy* and *dynamic programming*. Tactics include *don't overkill* and *recovery damage is cheap while reduced damage > initial damage / 5*. Hm. Order opponents by descending stamina, start with the strongest one not above *damage*, but above *damageReduction*. Have the strongest standing take the rest. Ah, lots of dangling ends… Have fun!